Time derivative of moment of inertia tensor
Suppose that I have some fluid in a fixed volume. Its moment of inertia is given by $I=\int\rho r^2dV$. The derivative of $I$ is given by $\dot{I}=\int\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}r^2dV$. Why do we not differentiate the $r^2$ term? If I had written the same thing for a discrete system of moving particles whose mass varies with time, I would have differentiated both terms. For a fluid, $\rho$ varies with time, by virtue of motion of the fluid, so I suppose that this situation is different from discrete particles. My guess is that it has something to do with the fact that variation in density is caused by fluid motion while $r$ just refers to a fixed coordinate in this case, but somehow I can't get it clear in my head. Is there a more strict mathematical way of thinking about it?

Do you have context surrounding the formula you gave? The answer you seek could just be buried in the reasoning there. It could also be that the derivative term was zero for some given reason and so they don't write it.

It's from the derivation of the virial equation. I was following this- https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Sept10/Krumholz/Krumholz3.html

Assuming the axis remains constant, strictly speaking, the time dependence is due to the change in $\rho$. I think that the confusion arises because $\rho$ is used to refer to two different things. The first is the density or mass of the object which is very often constant. The second is the actual density function $\rho(\mathbf{r},t)$. When we evaluate the moment of inertia integral, we are really using the latter. When the time derivative of this integral is taken, there won't be any boundary terms as the integral is taken over all space. Therefore, we only need to take the time derivative of the integrand, $\rho r^2$.
Intuitively, $r^2$ can be thought of as a "weight factor" that scales the contribution of the mass elements by their distance to the axis. When thought of this way, it should be clear that it only varies with space and is constant with respect to time.
For example, in the case of a single particle initially located at $(x_0,0)$ and moving along the $x$-axis with speed $v$,
$$\rho r^2 = m\delta(x-x_0-vt)\delta(y)(x^2+y^2) \\ = m\delta(x-x_0-vt)\delta(y)((x_0+vt)^2+0^2)$$
and integrating this over all space, we get $I = m(x_0+vt)^2$ and this might have misled you into thinking that $r^2$, and not $m$, varied with time, even though the quantity that is actually changing is $\rho(\mathbf{r},t)$. The property of the delta function, which is that it is zero everywhere except $(x_0+vt,0)$, i.e. it picks out the value in its argument, gives the illusion that $r^2$ is changing when it really isn't.
As long as $\rho(\mathbf{r},t)$ is defined properly, using delta and indicator/window functions where appropriate, there won't be any need to differentiate $r^2$.
If the rotation axis itself changed with time, then the above reasoning will of course fail and the problem becomes much more difficult, which is why the body frame (leading to Euler's equations) is often used.
